# Read all the rows of a CSV

Tags: python, csv

Hey I have this code that concatenate all the csv files of a folder in a only csv file. The problem is that this line of code `if i! = 0:` prevents the first row of each csv from being read except in the first csv. Any ideas on how to modify it so that it can read all the rows of the csv

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


import pandas as pd
import glob, os
import shutil

#import csv files from folder
path = r'/Users/sonia/Animalsmanage/output'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

with open('finaloutput.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline() 
                outfile.write(bytearray(b'\n'))   # add a empty line
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Comment: You've identified the `i != 0` as the culprit.  So, what happens if you take that block out (i.e. it `if` and/or some/all of the indented lines following it)?

Comment: If I take it out I could not separate each csv by a blank line and the phython 3x gives me an error. Even so, that block should act not reading the first row, but when I execute it, it does not read the first two, I do not know why.

Comment: It looks to me like `infile...` is responsible for discarding the first row of the input and `outfile.write...` is responsible for the blank line.  It sounds like you just want to discard the former.  It could help to post more details about what you tried and what error Python gives you.

Comment: If I discard `if i != 0:
                infile.readline() ` keep reading 49 rows of the 50 that I have.

Comment: And if you just remove `infile.readline()`, it doesn't behave as you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to include all the rows from the input file and separate the output of each input file by a blank, you can try this:

```
with open('finaloutput.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            outfile.write(bytearray(b'\n'))
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

So if I have 3 input files:

**test1.csv:**

```
name,id
dan,22
keith,23
```

**test2.csv:**

```
name,id
mike,33
phil,44
```

**test3.csv:**

```
name,id
john,5
peter,6
```

My output file will contain:

```
name,id
dan,22
keith,23

name,id
mike,33
phil,44

name,id
john,5
peter,6
```

**EDIT:**
If you don't want the blank line at the end, you can use the following instead:

```
numFiles = len(allFiles)
with open('finaloutput.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            if i < numFiles - 1:
                outfile.write(bytearray(b'\n'))
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Comment: This adds a blank line at the end. Not sure if OP cares. But half the reason for the `if` in the first place is to not do that.

Comment: @tdelaney Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated my post to address that.